# How to replace some of Bootstrap responsive design JQuery dependencies with another Javascript library?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, dojo, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

My project uses Dojo toolkit 1.9, so I do not want to include JQuery, what are the relevant parts of Bootstrap's JQuery scripts which I need to replace for the responsive design features?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The responsive navbar uses Bootstrap's [Collapse jQuery plugin](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse).

[Respond.js](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond) is only necessary for IE8, and doesn't use jQuery.

Other than that, all the responsiveness is achieved via CSS media queries, not JavaScript.

Comment: Accepting this answer as responsive navbar was the feature which was not working without Javascript for me.

Answer (score 2):

The responsive design features do not require JavaScript as far as I know, so you can just use the Twitter Bootstrap CSS file without the JavaScript code (then you don't need jQuery as well).

If you're interesting in the other features of Twitter Bootstrap as well (tabs, scrollspy, modals, tooltips, ...) then the [Dojo Bootstrap](http://dojobootstrap.com/) project may be interesting for you.

If you're also interested in using standard Dojo widgets with a Bootstrap theme, then you can also take a look at the [Dojo Bootstrap Theme](http://thesociable.github.io/dbootstrap/).